# textbox will display the string depending on which checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with 3 checkbox and 1 textbox..I want to display a string in textbox depending on which checkbox is tick.

chkProcessor is tick = Processor is the brain of computer...

chkRam is tick = RAM stick usually we call it memory

chkCmos is tick = It's like a coin type battery..

if 2 or more checkbox is tick then it will display their respective string.

this is the form

[image]

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub chkCmos_Click()

If chkCmos.Value = True Then
txtVerbiage.Text = txtVerbiage.Text & "It's like a coin type battery.." & Chr(10)

Else

' I WANT THE ABOVE TEXT TO BE NOT DISPLAYED THEN

End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkProcessor_Click()

If chkProcessor.Value = True Then

    txtVerbiage.Text = txtVerbiage.Text & "Processor is the brain of computer..." & Chr(10)

    'I WANT TO HAVE A LINE BREAK HERE.

    txtVerbiage.Text = txtVerbiage.Text & "Normally sets below the heat sink..." & Chr(10)

Else

' I WANT THE ABOVE TEXT TO BE NOT DISPLAYED THEN


End If

End Sub

Private Sub chkRam_Click()

If chkRam.Value = True Then

txtVerbiage.Text = txtVerbiage.Text & "RAM stick usually we call it memory" & Chr(10)


Else

' I WANT THE ABOVE TEXT TO BE NOT DISPLAYED THEN


End If

End Sub



Private Sub cmdErase_Click()
txtComment.Text = ""
txtVerbiage.Text = ""
chkProcessor.Value = False
chkRam.Value = False
chkCmos.Value = False
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) I assume textbox is initially blank? 2) I assume if customer deselects checkbox then text should also be removed from textbox 3) If more than 1 checkbox checked, should text appear in certain order, have line breaks between text?

Comment: Yes that is correct Alex...if 2 or more checkbox is check, it should display their string in order with a line break..I'm really having trouble with that though..

Comment: I can send you the file if you want to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub chkProcessor_Click()
    DisplayManager
End Sub

Private Sub chkRAM_Click()
    DisplayManager
End Sub

Private Sub chkCmos_Click()
    DisplayManager
End Sub

Sub DisplayManager()
    Dim cb As MSForms.Control, txt As String

    txt = vbNullString
    Me.txtVerbiage.Value = txt

    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctrl.Value Then
                txt = txt & GetMessage(ctrl.Name) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Me.txtVerbiage.Value = txt
End Sub

Function GetMessage(cbName As String) As String
    Dim str As String        
        If cbName = "chkProcessor" Then
            str = "Processor is the brain of computer..."
        ElseIf cbName = "chkRam" Then
            str = "RAM stick usually we call it memory"
        ElseIf cbName = "chkCmos" Then
            str = "It's like a coin type battery..."
        End If    
    GetMessage = str
End Function
```

- For `txtVerbiage` set `Multiline` to True (in VB editor properties)
- Each `chkXXX` calls `DisplayManager` to manage text display
- The text will appear in the order of the `chkXXX` on the Userform

Comment: Thank you so much Alex...Wow what a relief..i'm going to update now my tool..Thank you so much.

Comment: If I want to include another string, let say for Processor, I have like 2 or 3 sentences..

Comment: I would update the **GetMessage** function to handle that